# argument grouping with parenthesis are valid in C++?

Tags: c++11

On python I can group arguments into a tuple, something like

```
def func((a, b, c, d), x):
    print a, b, c, d, x
```

I was wondering if it is possible to group arguments in the same way on C++, something like:

```
void func((int a, int b, int c, int d), float x)
{
    cout << a << b << c << d << x << endl;
};
```

Comment: It's not possible, you'd have your function to take an `std::tuple<>` argument instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it can be done with [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
using namespace std;

void func(tuple<int, int, int, int> tup, float x)
{
    int a, b, c, d;
    tie(a, b, c, d) = tup;
    cout << a << b << c << d << x << endl;
}

int main() {
    func(make_tuple(1, 2, 3, 4), 5.5f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: On some (conformant, not VS2013) C++11 compilers, the function call can be made as `func({1, 2, 3, 4}, 5.5f);`. Note that the `using namespace std;` statement is not necessary for the solution, just a habit of the answerer.